# If $A,B$ and $AB$ are symmetric matrices then is $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ also symmetric.

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics, symmetric-matrices

if $ A,B$ and$ AB$ are symmetric matrices then is $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ also symmetric ?

my approach:
since $$AB=BA$$,
pre multiply by $A^{-1}$ and then post multiply by $A^{-1}$ to get

$$BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$$

hence I was able to prove that $BA^{-1} and A^{-1}B $ are symmetric.(taking transpose and applying reversal property)

but using this nothing could be concluded for 
$A^{-1}B^{-1}$

so is there any way to prove or disprove that $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ is symmetric? thanks for your help.

Comment: You get $BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$, not $BA^{-1}=AB^{-1}$.

Comment: @TonyK yes,edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(A^{-1}B^{-1})^T &= (B^{-1})^T(A^{-1})^T\\
&= (B^{T})^{-1}(A^{T})^{-1}\\
&= (B)^{-1}(A)^{-1}\\
&= B^{-1}A^{-1}\\
&= (AB)^{-1}\\
&= (BA)^{-1}\\
&= A^{-1}B^{-1} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

(A^-1B^-1)^T =  (B^-1)^T(A^-1)^T
                       = (B^T)^-1(A^T)^-1
                       = (B^-1)(A^-1)
                      =(AB)^-1
                     = (BA)^-1
                       = A^-1.B^-1

Comment: thanks!got the answer